# Returning the factors of a polynomial as a vector in Pari/GP

Tags: polynomials, pari, pari-gp

When using `factor`, Pari prints the factors of a polynomial and their multiplicities. When using, say, `polcyclofactors`, however, the cyclotomic factors of the polynomial are listed as a vector, without multiplicity.

Is there are way to mimic `polcyclofactors` when just simply factoring polynomials? So, to just display the factors of the polynomial as a vector, without worrying about multiplicities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The function `factor` returns a two column matrix. If you are only interested in the primes, not the multiplicities you can select just the first column:

For example:

```
factor(120)[,1]
```

If you were only interested in the multiplicities you would do `[,2]`. If you need the result as a vector rather than a column vector (the two types are mostly interchangeable), then you also need to add a conversion:

```
Vec(factor(120)[,1])
```

Although, I have done my examples with an integer, it also works with polynomials.

```
Vec(factor((1+x)^7*(1+x^2)^3)[,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant on Andrew's answer: you can convert a matrix into the vector of its columns using `Vec`, then (multi-)assign individual columns to new variables, so that

```
[P] = Vec(factor(120));
```

sets `P` to the vector of irreducible factors and

```
[P, E] = Vec(factor(120));
```

sets `P` and `E` to irreducible factors and multiplicities respectively. But the more messy factor()[,1] construct will be a little faster (because calling `Vec` causes extra copies).